# Substitute for horseradish?

Tags: substitutions, vegetables, spices, mustard

**What are some good substitutes for horseradish?**

I've heard mustard is one, but I still struggle a bit to see how it would do a very good job...

- Anybody ever try mustard with success?

I've also seen online that some people suggest wasabi, but let's be honest, the "wasabi" that most of us are familiar with [*is actually* horseradish](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/fake-wasabi-horseradish_us_561bd666e4b0082030a33959).

(Oh, and please don't suggest horseradish sauce -_- . That one is obvious).

---

*Update:*

I like horseradish, but **horseradish is not available** at my local market.

I'm just **trying to achieve the same sharp/pungent "kick" that horseradish typically brings**. The flavor is almost immaterial; I just want the "kick".

- As such, I'm not particular to trying it in any specific dish. I'm just curious **what other foods can produce a similar feeling/tasting "kick" as horseradish**.

Note: Wasabi is also not available at my local market.

Comment: For which use case?

Comment: Just looking for an alternative to achieve that sharp/pungent taste associated with horseradish. For any dish, really.

Comment: @theforestecologist: unfortunately, it's almost impossible to suggest a substitute unless we know what it's for. Are you trying to substitute because you can't get horseradish, or because you don't like horseradish? If the latter, what is it about horseradish that you don't like? What sort of dish is this for? How big a component of the original dish is the horseradish?

Comment: Why not just use... horseradish?

Comment: Do you need an alternative because of Allergies, Cost, Availability,
You Dislike the Flavor, Physical Properties (e.g. needs to stand higher/lower temp,) Appearance, Aesthetic Appropriateness (e.g. like X but fits in with Indian flavors?) These could all trigger very different responses. Most people ask for an appropriate substitute because they don't have the ingredient on hand, so wasabi would be an immediate go-to response; it would not be an appropriate response if you didn't like the flavor of horseradish, or had an allergy to it.

Comment: Pure ammonia will produce the same nose-burning agony as horseradish. Unlike other suggestions ammonia is also toxic and inedible and so a more accurate substitute.

Comment: Some mustards have horseradish in them. Can you not buy horseradish paste/powder online?

Comment: It's a whole lot milder, but does your local market have plain ol' radish? The other alternative is to acquire horseradish seed and plant it in a pot (not out in a garden, because it'll take over and you'll never be able to get rid of it).

Comment: You're going to have a tough time substituting horseradish with anything else if you're after the same "nose burn" effect. Horseradish, and Wasabi fumes travel up your nasal passages and result in the "kick" you're talking about... horseradish sauce can indeed be used in most recipes that call for horseradish in my experience. Finding raw horseradish at the store is sort of rare.

Comment: @JPmiaou you know, you're right. Radishes can have a slight "bite" to them. I wonder how I could accentuate that....

Comment: @SnakeDoc good point about the fumes causing nose burn. The substitute would need strong volatiles I reckon...

Comment: Horseradish powder is available however I don’t know how much powder can substitute for fresh

Comment: mustard powder, not prepared mustard

Answer (score 4):

Mustard can be used, but it might have a lot of vinegar in it and can clash with whatever you are doing.

Maybe try doing something with mustard powder instead of prepared mustared.

You could try, if you are luck to get some real fresh Wasabi roots; that would be close to the perfect substitution.

Comment: I've never noticed that pungent of a flavor from powdered mustard. But perhaps it needs to be fresh to retain any true "kick"?

Answer (score 4):

Horseradish has distinctive tones which you can't replicate from other ingredients, neither is there a single substitution you can make. The closest I think you would get is a mixture of ginger and mustard. I would try blitzing together some fresh ginger root and crushed mustard seed, maybe with a dash of vinegar. A good, strong prepared mustard might work, if you can get something like Colemans (a British brand) you could try it as a substitute on its own or mix it with ginger.

Answer (score 2):

Prepared whole grain or course ground mustards usually have less of a vinegar taste and more spice/kick, similar to what you get with raw horseradish. If you go with mustard, I'd choose one of this variety rather than standard yellow mustard.